# pandas dataframe doesn't give expected results

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, data-analysis

I have a dataframe, with 10 unique user id's, against these 10 user id's there are almost 3200 entries. Now what I want to do is, to select 8 out of 10 user id's. Since user id are complex 16 bit names, I have a python dictionary that is from 1 to 10 and every index stores a unique user_id. Here's the code snippet

```
users_dict={}
j=1
for user in users:
    users_dict[j]=user
    j+=1
```

Now when i want to exclude 2 user_id from dataframe and get a new dataframe, I use the following code

```
retailers=[1,2,3,5,6,7,8,10]
retailers_list=retailers.copy()
for i in range(len(retailers)):
    retailers[i]=users_dict[retailers[i]]
```

I get the expected output without user 4 and 9 in retailers.
Then I use the following code to get a dataframe with the specified users only

```
retailers=df['user_id'].isin(retailers)
retailers=df.loc[retailers]
```

After getting the users, I apply some queries which I've applied before on the original data too and then plot it, but the user 4 and 9 are somehow in the new retailer dataframe. I plot on average transaction a user makes and average number of transactions but user 4 and 9 are somehow there, and user 3 and 8 are somehow excluded.
Help please.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you have datasets in pandas DataFrame.

To get the distinct values among tons of user_id, you can try this piece of code:

```
# transfer user_id values into list

users_list = users['user_id'].values.tolist()

# get unique values from a list

import collections
print([item for item, count in 

collections.Counter(users_list).items() if count > 1])
```

The users_dict you created can separate all user_ids into 10 unique groups.

```
# create users_dict to represent each observation and group them into 10 groups

users_dict={}
j=1
for user in users_list:
    users_dict[j]=user
    j+=1
```

Here, You can just keep retailers as a list that counts from 1 to 10 without 4 and 9.

```
# retailer list containing the user_id that you want

retailers=[1,2,3,5,6,7,8,10]
```

Then you can run the last piece of your code.

```
# subset users with user_id from 1 to 10 without 4 and 9

retailers=users['user_id'].isin(retailers_list)

retailers=users.loc[retailers]
```

I think you can get the ideal results now.

The issue may lie in the second part of your code when you rewrite the values in retailers.

Comment: it may help if you look at the [markdown editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) - it can make it clearer to read the code piece of your answer.